# Security Concerns When placing .* (dot star) in Django URL Conf Regex

Tags: regex, django, security, url

I have a view which fetches a file and serves it to the user. The view is as follows:

```
@login_required
def file(request, mid_id, file_name):
    user = request.user

    authorized_mids = user.profile.authorized_mids(True)

    mid = get_object_or_404(Mid, id=mid_id)
    try:
        authorized_mids[mid.id]
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404

    mid_file_path = settings.PATH_TO_REPORTS + ('/%s/' % mid.pk) + file_name

    to_return = open(mid_file_path, 'r')

    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(mid_file_path)

    response = HttpResponse(to_return, mimetype=mimetype)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name;

    return response
```

My URL looks like:

```
url(r'^mid/(?P<mid_id>\d+)/file/(?P<file_name>.*?)/$', 'mid.views.file', name='fetch_report')
```

Are there any security concerns with having the .* in the URL? Will a (malicious) user be able to hack in such a way that they will be able to access files which they should not be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably replace the `.*?` with `[^#?]*?` to avoid matching the query or fragment portions of the URL or use [`urllib.parse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html) to separate out the path portion.

Also, be aware of `..` sequences in URLs.

```
r'^mid/(?P<mid_id>\d+)/file/(?P<file_name>.*?)/$'
```

matches

```
mid/1/file/../../../../etc/
```

which is outside the `mid/1/file` subdirectory tree.

You could do

```
os.path.normpath(path)
```

before running the regex which should reject the above because

```
os.path.normpath('mid/1/file/../../../../etc/')
```

is

```
../etc
```

but you will have to remove the `/` before `$` and `normpath` might behave differently on Windows machines than on *nix.  I don't know of any equivalent to `normpath` in the `urllib` module.